# how to add queue tasks to threadpool in C#

Tags: c#, queue, threadpool, addition, task

I'm still new at this threading thingy. Lets say I have 50000 URLs and I want to get the contents of these URLs simultaneously, like processing every 10 URLs together. then once one of these URLs finishes processing, the program should add another 1 from the queue list until it finishes processing all URLs in the list. now how can I do that with C#.. here is the code I'm doing so far..

```
 class RequestState
        {
            public WebRequest Request;

        // holds the request 
        public object Data;

        // store any data in this 
        public string SiteUrl;

        // holds the UrlString to match up results (Database lookup, etc). 

        public RequestState(WebRequest request, object data, string siteUrl)
        {
            this.Request = request;
            this.Data = data;
            this.SiteUrl = siteUrl;
        }
    }

    private void PROCESS_URLS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //run the process
        process_URLs();
    }

private int ThreadsCount = 0;

  private void process_URLs()
    {
       //count threads number
        ThreadsCount = URLS_LISTVIEW.SelectedItems.Count;

       //loop through all URLs in listview
        for (int i = 0; i < URLS_LISTVIEW.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                //get url string
                string myURLs = URLS_LISTVIEW.SelectedItems[i].SubItems[0].Text.Trim();

                // for each URL in the collection...
                WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(myURLs);
                request.Method = "GET";
                object data = new object();

                RequestState state = new RequestState(request, data, myURLs);
                IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(UpdateItem), state);
                ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(ScanTimeoutCallback), state, (30 * 1000), true);

            }
            catch (ThreadStateException es)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
            }

        }



    }




 private void UpdateItem(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        RequestState state = (RequestState)result.AsyncState;
        WebRequest request = (WebRequest)state.Request;
        try
        {// grab the custom state object
            // get the Response
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

            // process the response...
            Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(s);

            //data grabbed
            string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            s.Close();
            readStream.Close();



        //finished grabbing content for this thread.
        ThreadsCount = ThreadsCount - 1;


        //if all threads finished running then execute final code to tell the user the process finished
        if (ThreadsCount < 1)
        {
            //show message
            MessageBox.Show("finished");
        }

       // Thread.Sleep(400);

    }





private static void ScanTimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
    {
        if (timedOut)
        {
            RequestState reqState = (RequestState)state;

            if (reqState != null)
                reqState.Request.Abort();


        }
    }
```

any ideas would be appreciated :)

kind regards,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the TPL, there's an option to specify the maximum parallelism:

```
List<string> UriList = new List<string>();
...
Parallel.ForEach(UriList, 
                 new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism=10}, 
                 (x) =>
{
    ProcessUrl(x);
});
```

This would process at most 10 Urls in parallel since we use the overload of [`Parallel.Foreach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747.aspx) that allow us to specify [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx).

**Edit:**

Here a simple example that downloads the Html from http://google.com 50 times in parallel (but only at a maximum with 10 threads concurrently) and stores the results in an array:

```
List<string> UriList = new List<string>();
for(int i =0;i<50;i++)
    UriList.Add("http://google.com");

string[] HtmlResults = new string[UriList.Count];

Parallel.ForEach(UriList, 
                 new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, 
                 (url, i, j) =>
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    HtmlResults[j] = wc.DownloadString(url);
});
```

Not to create more confusion but in your particular case [PLINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx) would also work very well since there are no dependencies between the item to process, and you have an actual result that the URL is "transformed" into:

```
var htmlResultList = UriList.AsParallel()
                            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
                            .AsOrdered()
                            .Select(url => { WebClient wc = new WebClient(); return wc.DownloadString(url); })
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: this means I need to wrote the whole thing from scratch?

Comment: you can still re-use the code that actually *processes* a Url, like the `WebRequest` etc. - but personally I would even simplify that by using a `WebClient`. Think of the long term benefit though - there is much, much less code to maintain.

Comment: @ermac2014: Updated with an example

Comment: thanks for this :).. but now when I run the code the whole UI freezes until it finishes grabbing all contents from the 50 URLs any ideas?

Comment: @ermac2014: The `Parallel.Foreach()` statement will only finish once all content has been downloaded - it's synchronous. If you want it to be asynchronous you'd have to spawn a thread to run it in, i.e wrap it in a `Task`.

Comment: I will try that.. thanks for your help and the easy examples you added.. now it makes more sense :) really appreciated..

Comment: This example only sets the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. What we need to set is a min value, which can be set from `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`, otherwise you're (usually)going to fetch as many url's as there are cores in your system.

Answer (score 3):

(This should be a comment under @BrokenGlass, but I can't post comments yet)

You can take a look at [this article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx) on how to use Parallel Processing and PLINQ to do what you're looking for.  The entire set of articles that precede it have some good information as well.

Edit:  If this is a standalone, spawn a new thread to run this portion in the background so it doesn't result in an unresponsive UI.

Edit 2: If you want, you can also throw your strings in a [ConcurrentQueue](http://bit.ly/hs829Y) so you can add items from the UI while looking them up.

Comment: you mean I need to use a new thread to do this or to use background worker? or it doesn't matter both will do same thing..?

Comment: @ermac2014 - You can do either.  Just pushing the work off to some other thread not associated with your UI will keep it from hanging.  Then, when the work is complete, just have some callback update the UI with the results.

Comment: well now that makes sense :) I will let you know if I need further help. thank you for the tips really appreciated..

Comment: No worries!  Glad if I could be of assistance.